# Making a Pipeline available to any Application

Tags: biztalk

I have a pipeline that I need to reuse.  I need to be able to chose this pipeline from any app  as I can with the XML or the Passthrough pipelines.

Is there a way to publish a pipeline to the Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you have the asnwer but I want to clarify a couple of things.

As you're discovered, BizTalk.System is a readonly system Application and cannot be modified.

The .Net namespace Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines actually has nothing to do with it.

For all your shared components, you would create a new Application container in BizTalk Administrator called "My Shared Components" or such.

Then Add Reference to this Application to make Pipelines and Maps deployer there available in the local Application.

Final point, Add Reference only affects the visibility of Pipelines and Maps in BT Admin Port Configurations.  Any other GAC'd components are available by the standard .Net rules.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, can't you deploy (add resource) to BizTalk.System?

Comment: You have put me in the right direction.  It's Add reference!!
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/70c9920b-eced-4bc9-bba5-77c22451d556/how-to-add-resources-to-biztalksystem

This way I can build a base app, and use it like a utility whore.

Comment: Glad to help - but I'm no pimp! :-)

Comment: And apologies to all - if I had spent 2 minutes verifying my suggestion, I would know NOT to suggest BizTalk.System in the first place!!!